# Negative values in ArcGIS API for Flex app?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, map-service, query-layer

I have a contractor working for me on a Flex application. He retrieves recordset for a intersect query from the web service published in house. But he is getting some ids as negative random number instead of integer (generally 9-10 digits). 
He says it is at our end but when I query from REST service, I get everything fine. He is using the query to display results in app.

I don't know his code in details because I have tasks to develop server side functionalities and have my plate full.

The mapping service, in question, is a query layer and retrieving data from ORACLE database.

Has anyone else noticed similar behavior? or any suggestion on this?

Comment: We checked against Oracle database and in REST URL these are mostly the numbers greater than 300,000,000. But numbers greater than 800,000,000 are fine. We tried converting one of the negative numbers to some other number range (e.g. 11155666), then it was working. We are not sure what is causing this problem.

Comment: It might be a integer overflow error. What is the data type that you are using for storing these numbers?

Comment: @user8732, ..does your comment imply that you isolated the problem as occurring server-side, or are the remarks in your question still correct—specifically, when you *query from REST service, [you] get everything fine*?

Comment: This was solved long back; Sorry I forgot to update here. I added the ID variable casted as 'String' in my WMS and used in Flex app. ESRI recognized this issue and apparently ESRI has fixed this problemin new version of Flex API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few thoughts to help you move forward.

**1. Prove once and for all to everyone that the problem is unquestionably server-side:**

If I were the Flex dev, I would use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (or any other traffic sniffer) and show you a screenshot *proving* the errant values are emitting from your service layer *before they get into Flex*. In other words, make them prove it. ( ..surely they've already done this, right? But if they haven't, they may very well prove *to themselves* that the problem occurs when the data hits Flex. I hope you're not in that situation. :/ )

**2A. Cast the id values as String, server-side:** My recommendation? Just do this and be done with it. Assuming you prove Flex is the bad guy in #1, I'd cut to the chase and cast your `id` values to String server-side, like [this guy](http://abadjimarinov.net/blog/2010/06/24/ActionScript3NumberDataTypeProblemWithLongIntegerValues.xhtml), and [this guy](http://www.curiousfind.com/blog/183). If you do that, it eliminates every variety of "Flex-wierd-number-stuff".

**2B. Configure return data types, client-side:** ..alternatively, your Flex dev can "[configure the return data type](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WSbde04e3d3e6474c4-668f02f4120d422cf08-7ff7.html)" for the `id` values, forcing the Flex client to receive them as String values. This saves you some trouble server-side, but personally, I'm not a big fan of this approach for the reason that if I have to delete/recreate my service connection in Flex, I have to remember all the specific return types I've configured. (And sometimes this is necessary if anything is refactored or heavily revised server-side.) But this is just personal preference based on my experiences.

**2C. Implement a unique solution, client-side, to handle large integer values:** This is an option, but it's not necessary to get where you want to be. Nevertheless your Flex dev could experiment with [this so-called `BigInt` class](http://kingtut666.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/bigint-in-actionscript-3-0/) (or anything else like it, plucked from the web). I rank this as option 2C because, well—you'd be involving a class someone created and put on their blog. :) Nothing wrong with that, but casting to `String` removes all guess-work.

The truth is I love Flex for the stuff it does well, like rendering rich, visual content—and that's perfect for online maps. But I avoid doing serious arithmetic or buisness logic in Flex. Not to be pessimistic, but if you see clean data when you poll the service layer directly, I automatically suspect the issue begins when the data hits Flex. There's just no shortage of [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568449/as3-number-type-logic-issues-with-large-numbers) about [this and similar issues](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?318942-Number-type-acting-whacky-storing-incorrect-number) if you do [some looking](https://www.google.com/search?q=actionscript%20Big%20Number)..

Best of luck. /E

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have that problem but did have an issue with dates.
You can use numeric formatting that may solve the problem (if not already doing so).

```
<field name="mydate_stat" alias="Date submitted" visible="true">
        <format dateformat="shortDate" useutc="true"/>
        </field>
```

This code doesn't apply but gives an example of how field formatting in flex is used.
Here is how I format to get no comma and no decimals.

```
<field name="meter_id" alias="Meter ID" visible="true">
        <format usethousandsseparator="false" precision="0"/>
```

[Adobe has some information here.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=formatters_2.html)
for the mx.formatters.formatter class
[with more here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/Formatter.html)